# Merge url-rewriting and urlrewrite tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

On Stack Overflow, we have:

[url-rewriting](/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) - 2286 questions

[urlrewrite](/questions/tagged/urlrewrite) - 274 questions

I suggest that we make [urlrewrite](/questions/tagged/urlrewrite) a synonym of [url-rewriting](/questions/tagged/url-rewriting).